# validation on existing collections before updating or addToSet in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express

I am working on MongoDB validaiton where in i have to validate the fields which are dynamically created though a form . I am using ExpressJs and want that before updating the existing collection it should validate the required field or mandatory field. Is it possible to validate the value while updating the field.

Answer (score 0):

yes. it is possible refer [mongoDB validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/document-validation/)  for validating the fields.

you can also refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) to store functions on mongoDB.

I would recommend you to validate the fields in express and update in mongo if you are opting for the 2nd approach.

Comment: can you give me example for the same. I have tired but as i m new could not able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
db.runCommand( {
   collMod: "your_collection",
   validator: { $and: [ { required_field1: { $exists: true } }, { required_field1: { $exists: true } } ] },
} )
```